# Qt.FramelessWindowHint not working on QInputDialog

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6, qinputdialog

I'm learning PySide6 and I'm trying to create a frameless QInputDialog.

When I set:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QInputDialog, QMainWindow


app = QApplication()

input_dialog = QInputDialog(flags=Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
text, ok = input_dialog.getText(QMainWindow(), 'input dialog', 'Is this ok?')
if ok:
    print(text)

app.exec()
```

the frame still appears. Why?

[image]

Comment: @eyllanesc edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The getText method is static so `input_dialog` is not the displayed window but an instance of QInputDialog is created internally, so you must pass the flags through the method:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QInputDialog

app = QApplication()

text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(
    None, "input dialog", "Is this ok?", flags=Qt.FramelessWindowHint
)
if ok:
    print(text)
```